# how to tell whether a connection is established in java?

Tags: java, android, nio, socketchannel

I tried to build a socket channel between two emulators in android. I wrote the following code:

```
    public SocketChannel connect2node(String ip, int port) {
        SocketChannel client = null;
        try {
            client = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
            client.configureBlocking(false);
            client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

            if (!client.isConnected()) {
                Log.i("server connection", "error");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String s = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return client;
    }
```

Note I have NOT started another emulator in (ip, port), means the connection will always fail. When I start debugging the above code, I found when it came to

```
    if (!client.isConnected()) {
```

It then jumps to the catch block:

```
     e.printStackTrace();
```

all other lines in catch block is not executed, and the client is not null when return. So how can I tell whether the connection is successfully established or not?

Comment: What does the stack trace say?

Comment: It print nothing. I think it skipped `e.printStackTrace()` too.

Comment: Impossible. I suggest you recompile and retest. See also my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The isConnected() test is pointless. If the open() fails to connect it will throw an exception.

Comment: The open() succeed, and the code goes on until isConnected() then throws an exception.

Comment: @zwx Yes, I read that in your question. Doesn't affect my answer in the slightest. Just remove the test. It is futile. The socket cannot be non-connected at that point in the code.

Comment: yes, you are right. After I remove the `isConnected()` test it doesn't throw an exception and goes well. But my question is how to tell whether the connection is established or not? Because the `client` is returned as non-null value, I can't distinguish it from successful connection.

Comment: @zwx I have just answered that, twice: (1) 'If the open() fails to connect it will throw an exception' (2) 'The socket cannot be non-connected at that point in the code'.`open()` didn't throw an exception, so the channel is connected, and execution continues sequentially. That's why the following test is futile.

Comment: Thanks for your explaining, but my question is not really about that. Since the remote emulator at (ip, port) can be either running or haven't started yet, I need a way to know that whether the emulator is listening or not ready. I hope the connection will fail if the emulator is not listening, and success otherwise.

Comment: @zwx If the connection succeeded there was something listening at the other end.